# How to store the results of an iteration over rows of a Pandas DataFrame in a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I am new to coding in Python. Currently, I am trying to analyse a dataframe containing multiple workflows. Each workflow has a different process steps for initiating and ending a workflow. In a simplified version, my data looks like the following:

```
   Workflow Initiate   End_1   End_2   End_3
0         1   Name_1      na  Name_1      na
1         2   Name_2      na      na      na
2         3   Name_3      na      na  Name_5
3         4   Name_4  Name_5      na      na
4         5       na      na      na  Name_5
```

For every workflow, I want to compare whether the name that ended the workflow is different as the name that initiated the workflow.

Iterating through the rows in the following way gives me the desired output:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if ((row['Initiate'] != 'na')
        and (row['Initiate'] == row['End_1']) |
            (row['Initiate'] == row['End_2']) |
            (row['Initiate'] == row['End_3'])
        ):
        print("Name end equals initiate")
    elif ((row['End_1'] == 'na') &
          (row['End_2'] == 'na') &
          (row['End_3'] == 'na')
         ):
        print("No name ended")
    else:
        print("Different name ended")

Name end equals initiate
No name ended
Different name ended
Different name ended
Different name ended
```

However, I want to add an extra column, say 'Analysis', in the dataframe that shows the above outcome behind every workflow.

For this I stuffed the code into a function:

```
def function_name(a, b, c, d):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if ((a != 'na')
            and (a == b) |
                (a == c) |
                (a == d)
            ):
            return "Name end equals initiate"
        elif ((b == 'na') &
              (c == 'na') &
              (d == 'na')
             ):
            return "No name ended"
        else:
            return "Different name ended"

df['Analysis'] = function_name(row['Initiate'],
                               row['End_1'],
                               row['End_2'],
                               row['End_3'])

print(df)

   Workflow Initiate          ...            End_3              Analysis
0         1   Name_1          ...               na  Different name ended
1         2   Name_2          ...               na  Different name ended
2         3   Name_3          ...           Name_5  Different name ended
3         4   Name_4          ...               na  Different name ended
4         5       na          ...           Name_5  Different name ended
```

As you can see the output is different from the first analysis. I would like to add an extra column to my dataframe that gives me the same output as with the print statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid row-wise loops here. Your algorithm is vectorisable:

```
df = df.replace('na', np.nan)  # replace string 'na' with NaN for efficient processing
ends = df.filter(like='End')  # filter by columns with 'End'

match = ends.ffill(1).iloc[:, -1] == df['Initiate']  # find last Name in each End
nulls = ends.isnull().all(1)  # check which rows are all null

# apply vectorised conditional logic
df['Result'] = np.select([match, nulls], ['Name end equals initiate', 'No name ended'],
                         'Different name ended')

print(df)

   Workflow Initiate   End_1   End_2   End_3                    Result
0         1   Name_1     NaN  Name_1     NaN  Name end equals initiate
1         2   Name_2     NaN     NaN     NaN             No name ended
2         3   Name_3     NaN     NaN  Name_5      Different name ended
3         4   Name_4  Name_5     NaN     NaN      Different name ended
4         5      NaN     NaN     NaN  Name_5      Different name ended
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I managed to apply it to my case and seems to work.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you forward fill the rows with every name that is found in the ends. It could be the case that there are multiple different names in the ends. In that case, iloc only looks for matches between the initiate name and the last name found and not (one of) the names before. Is there a way to adjust this so that it looks for a match between the initiate name and all the different names in the ends?

Comment: @Rens, There is a way, but it's not a trivial change to the logic. If you like, do ask a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), possibly referencing this one, and either I or another user can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use np.select()

```
conditions = [
    (df['Initiate'] != 'na') & ((df['Initiate'] == df['End_1']) | (df['Initiate'] == df['End_2']) | (df['Initiate'] == df['End_3'])),
    (df['End_1'] == 'na') & (df['End_2'] == 'na') & (df['End_3'] == 'na')
] 

answers = ['Name end equals initiate','No name ended']   
df['Analysis'] = np.select(conditions, answers, default='Different name ended')
```